# How do I return a struct value from a runtime-defined class method under ARC?

Tags: objective-c, struct, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-runtime, class-method

I have a class method returning a `CGSize` and I'd like to call it via the Objective-C runtime functions because I'm given the class and method names as string values.

I'm compiling with ARC flags in XCode 4.2.

Method signature:

```
+(CGSize)contentSize:(NSString *)text;
```

The first thing I tried was to invoke it with `objc_msgSend` like this:

```
Class clazz = NSClassFromString(@"someClassName);
SEL method = NSSelectorFromString(@"contentSize:");

id result = objc_msgSend(clazz, method, text);
```

This crashed with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and without a stack trace. I used this first because the documentation for `objc_msgSend` says,

> When it encounters a method call, the compiler generates a call to one of the functions `objc_msgSend`, `objc_msgSend_stret`, `objc_msgSendSuper`, or `objc_msgSendSuper_stret`. [...] Methods that have data structures as return values are sent using `objc_msgSendSuper_stret` and `objc_msgSend_stret`.

Next, I used `objc_msgSend_stret` like this:

```
Class clazz = NSClassFromString(@"someClassName);
SEL method = NSSelectorFromString(@"contentSize:");

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
objc_msgSend_stret(&size, clazz, method, text);
```

Using the above signature gives me the following two compiler errors and two warnings:

> error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'CGSize *' (aka 'struct CGSize *') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
>
> warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types passing 'CGSize *' (aka 'struct CGSize *') to parameter of type 'id'
>
> error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL' is disallowed with ARC
>
> warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types passing 
>       '__unsafe_unretained Class' to parameter of type 'SEL'

If I look at the declaration of the method, it is:

```
OBJC_EXPORT void objc_msgSend_stret(id self, SEL op, ...)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

which is identical to `objc_msgSend`:

```
OBJC_EXPORT id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

This explains the compiler errors to me but what do I use at the run-time level to invoke a class and its static method at run-time and return a struct value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to cast `objc_msgSend_stret` to the correct function pointer type. It's defined as `void objc_msgSend_stret(id, SEL, ...)`, which is an inappropriate type to actually call. You'll want to use something like

```
CGSize size = ((CGSize(*)(id, SEL, NSString*))objc_msgSend_stret)(clazz, @selector(contentSize:), text);
```

Here we're just casting objc_msgSend_stret to a function of type `(CGSize (*)(id, SEL, NSString*))`, which is the actual type of the `IMP` that implements `+contentSize:`.

Note, we're also using `@selector(contentSize:)` because there's no reason to use `NSSelectorFromString()` for selectors known at compile-time.

Also note that casting the function pointer is required even for regular invocations of `objc_msgSend()`. Even if calling `objc_msgSend()` directly works in your particular case, it's relying on the assumption that the varargs method invocation ABI is the same as the ABI for calling a non-varargs method, which may not be true on all platforms.

Comment: It turns out that you don't even want to use 'objc_msgSend_stret' but instead, objc_msgSend with the correct casting you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: @JonasGardner: I believe this is actually dependent upon the size of the struct and the architecture in question. It's very possible that `CGSize` on the architectures you care about are a simple `objc_msgSend()`. You'd need to consult the architecture ABI documentation to find out which struct sizes/types will be returned in registers versus returned on the stack.

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to retrieve a struct from your class method, you can use an NSInvocation as follows:

```
Class clazz = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"testMethod");

CGSize returnStruct; // Or whatever type you're retrieving

NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[clazz methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector]];

[invocation setTarget:clazz];
[invocation setSelector:aSelector];

[invocation invoke];
[invocation getReturnValue:&returnStruct];
```

At the end of this, `returnStruct` should contain your struct value.  I just tested this in an ARC-enabled application and this works fine.

Comment: `NSInvocation` is rather expensive. It's useful in many cases, but there are often faster ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @KevinBallard - Yup, just thought I'd throw it out there in case someone wanted a more abstracted solution than `objc_msgSend()`.

Comment: Fair enough. `NSInvocation` would also remove the confusion about which architectures use `objc_msgSend()` vs `objc_msgSend_stret()` for a given method.